# Can we install google play store applications directly from my app?

Tags: android, google-play, android-service

I am looking to download a Google Play Store application from my application so that the user can avoid going to the market and then click the install button.

Is it possible to install directly using background services?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to install directly using background services.

No. The user must be involved with any app installation, outside of rooted devices.